# Duplicate tweets entered in live twitter feed

Tags: jquery, html, json, live

Ive got a live update twitter thing that i have been trying to build, i notice sometimes it duplicates tweets and goes a little bit nuts. Have i stuffed up somewhere in here?

http://jsfiddle.net/JmZCE/1/

Thanks in advance
(note i posted something similar before but removed it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `pendingTweets` array inside `getJSON` callback handler because it needs to be initialized to empty array every time you get new tweets.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JmZCE/2/)**

After the first search `pendingTweets` has all the tweets from this call. Now in the next search you compare and add the add news tweets into this array you should empty it because you are looping through this array and building the markup.

Comment: @MrJD - Did you take a look at this?

Comment: Hi ShankarSangoli, I was under the impression that declaring an array multiple times is cumbersome. By removing all of the values until there are no values left before the ajax is finished i am emptying the array and effectively starting with a new one. If i was to declare each time i couldn't compare with the last one to check, thats why I'm using the rel attribute of the divs.

Comment: You are not comparing the against the array but you are find the first-child of every tweet and comparing against it[`if (item.id != $twitterDiv.find(':first-child:first').attr('rel'))`]. Thats why it didnt worked. You can just re initialize the array to empty arrary in the callback handler it is not at all cumbersome.

Comment: This is how re initialize to empty array `pendingTweets = [];` Take a look I modified the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JmZCE/3/.